# SSH to AWS VM from Mac OSX - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: macos, ssh, amazon-ec2

I downloaded the ssh key file `aws-ssh-key.pem.txt` to my Mac and moved it to my .ssh directory using

```
mv path/Downloads/aws-ssh-key.pem.txt ~./ssh/
```

When I list the contents of `.ssh` directory using `ls ~/.ssh` I see the following:

```
aws-ssh-key.pem.txt        id_rsa        known_hosts
config                     id_rsa.pub
```

Now, I run the below command from the `.ssh`.

```
ssh -v -i aws-ssh-key.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

And I get the below error:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: PATH/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: aws-ssh-key.pem.txt doesn't have .txt extension. .pem is extension itself. Also make sure that file have only read permission only from Owner only. You can assign that permission by sudo chmod 400 aws-ssh-key.pem

Comment: Yes sure, so that other can fix this type of problem.

Comment: @Chintan7027 Yeah because in the aws docs, it's not exactly clear. When I generated the ssh key it was automatically saved as a .txt file. I was wondering what that was.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html  Point (4) is useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aws-ssh-key.pem.txt doesn't have .txt extension.

Private key downloaded form AWS Console must have .pem extension. 
Also .pem file have only read permission for Owner only. You can assign that permission by sudo chmod 400 aws-ssh-key.pem

Note:
There is no need to move .pem key to ~/.ssh directory until and unless you want to add into ssh key pairs.

You can store .pem file in any safe directory and provide that path while ssh connection.